# Excessive outgoing data in vps

Tags: vps, network-traffic

I using [SuperWebSocket](https://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/), in a server application win32, framework 4.5, and My clients connect via web, all work fine, but it only for times, because in x hour(I do not know if this is related, but may perhaps be that the server tires), my vps host report me a DDoS attack is detected, and this is a graphics

[image]

SuperWebSocket no get nothing in error.log, I wanted to help me, to rule out possibilities

- Exhaustion server
- malware (note i rebuild the server 1 day ago)
- superwebsocket
- another possibility

Please how I can prevent this from happening, I think of some way to restart the vps if it detects more than 2000 requests (I think it's normal, if it is not because he is normal). Please I'm desperate

Answer (score 0):

From the information provided it is not possible to make a definitive conclusion in regards to the traffic spikes.
In order to determine the source, I would capture and analyze the traffic which will give you insight into the nature of the traffic and where the traffic is going.

In order to do so, you can either capture traffic directly at the switch via a SPAN capture or if you do not have access to that, capture locally on the machine via something like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)

Comment: wireshark activate until the server fails it ?, and it is possible that it is because the server ran out of resources